# Countdown with php database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, countdown

I'm trying to create a countdown using php and a database. I know that I can do it without a database, but this is for a school project and we need to use databases.

This is what I've got so far. But the value for $days_remaining comes out as -16210.

```
<?php 
include("php/db_connect.php");

//TODAY'S DATE
$today = time();

//FETCHES DATE AND TIME FOR THE EVENT FROM DATABASE
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countdown";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$date = mysql_fetch_array( $result );


//CALCULATES SECONDS UNTIL THE EVENT
$remaining = $date['date'] - $today;

//CALCULATE DAYS UNTIL THE EVENT
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);

echo "<div class='countdown'> $days_remaining days until event</div>";

?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$date['date']`?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: We all have to start from somewhere though...

Comment: Check on the meaning of your date values. What is stored in "days" in your database? Is it comparable to time() which will return a number of seconds since 1970-01-01 ?

Comment: @Coulton We don't have to start here! Not any more.

Comment: The value is 2015-08-05, stored as data type "date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't convert your date into a Unix Timestamp. As a result your math will not work. Change:

```
//CALCULATES SECONDS UNTIL THE EVENT
$remaining = $date['date'] - $today;
```

to:

```
//CALCULATES SECONDS UNTIL THE EVENT
$remaining = strtotime($date['date']) - $today;
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I will read up on PDO and MySQLi and perhaps get my headmaster fired.